# how to know block id in class which extend from BlockBase

Tags: 8, blocks

I am trying to get block id in my custom module  in build function of class which extends `BlockBase`.

How can i do this?

i want to use this block_id in another class controller to have configuration of that block so i think best place to get block id and send it to controller class is build function like below code

```
        class XController extends ControllerBase{
        ...
        $block = \Drupal\block\Entity\Block::load($block_id);
        if ($block) {
        ...
```

any other suggestion to do this is appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I programmatically display a block?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/171686/how-can-i-programmatically-display-a-block)

Comment: @leymannx that question is when we have block id and we want to display it. but i need that block id and after that i know what i want to do with it.

Comment: It's unclear what id you mean, but here https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/228593/how-can-i-access-block-metadata-from-custom-plugin-instance you'll find all id's you can get from a block.

Comment: @4k4 thanks. i checked that question. i need $block_id to use it  in \Drupal\block\Entity\Block::load($block_id); in a controller . i am trying to get that in build function of an extended BlockBase class and send it to that controller

Comment: If you want to use a block plugin class you have to instantiate it first, see `getPlugin()` in the linked answer.

Comment: @4k4 this is exactly like my question that you have responsed to it. https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/248324/is-there-a-way-to-figure-out-the-block-machine-name

Comment: @4k4 in that question is that possible to get 'machine_name_to_determine' in build() function of extended class from BlockBase?

Comment: The build() function in the block plugin class is unaware of the machine name (block id). There can be multiple blocks configured or no one at all if the plugin is built on the fly in custom code or by a layout module where the block configuration is stored in a different place than a block config entity you load in the question.

Comment: @4k4 thanks. maybe you should put comment at answer. i accept your answer. also i ended up with $variables['elements']['#id'] at modulename_preprocess_block function.

Comment: OK, if this is the solution the question should be, how to find the block id in a block template? Which can be easily answered, because the block template is the template of the block entity and not the block class the original question is about.

Comment: @4k4. I mean when you say block plugin class is not aware of block system name , it is a right answer for my original question so i tried to solve my problem in different way. You can post your comment as answer for my original question if you want. I really appreciate your help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`BlockBase` is a plugin, and as such has a [`getPluginId`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Component%21Plugin%21PluginBase.php/function/PluginBase%3A%3AgetPluginId/8.6.x) method. As you need this inside the class itself, it's as easy as:

```
$id = $this->getPluginId();
```

Comment: thanks. i wish that Drupal guide was simpler to find this things. I was able to get $id but does 'getpluginid()' return $block_id  which i need that $block = \Drupal\block\Entity\Block::load($block_id)? because i tested it and returns null.

Comment: maybe i have ask in another question but if i have two instance of block at page   getPluginId() returns same id for both of them,. block id shouln't be unique?

Comment: What’s the ID you’re expecting to see for each? Maybe you need `getDerivativeId` instead.

Comment: i don't know format of id  but i expect different ids. because different instances have different configuration. i need this ids to load their configuration in another controller with  \Drupal\block\Entity\Block::load($block_id).

Comment: Did you try the derivative ID?

Comment: $this->getDerivativeId() in build function returns null. maybe i miss something in my custom module?